# TLS implementation for Bluetooth

Tags: android, sockets, android-bluetooth, tls1.2, bluetooth-socket

How to implement TLS for Bluetooth application? I have to send and receive data over Bluetooth between android app and desktop application (python).

Please guide if someone had done this before.

Comment: why it is kept on hold?

Comment: Did you manage to have it working ?